# Laravel dynamic database connections

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I going to use dynamic database connections in backend.

```
        Config::set('database.connections._pgsql.host', $connection->host);
        Config::set('database.connections._pgsql.port', $connection->port);
        Config::set('database.connections._pgsql.username', $connection->account_name);
        Config::set('database.connections._pgsql.password', $connection->password);
        Config::set('database.connections._pgsql.database', $connection->initial_db);

        DB::purge('_pgsql');
        DB::reconnect('_pgsql');
```

As you see, I have to change db config every request to use dynamic db connections.
If there are concurrent requests with different db connections then how can I handle these requests and connections?

Please help me.

Comment: `Config::set` is a per-request action so it should still work with concurrent requests.

Comment: This is directly answered in the official Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#using-multiple-database-connections

Comment: Wow. really? Config::set only works per request? Where can I find documentation for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#using-multiple-database-connections) is good for a lot of situations, however, I find it to be more convenient in a lot of situations to set the connection in middleware. This is more tailored for multi-tenancy type apps but it may be useful for you:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // if a user belongs to an organization, company, team, etc.
    // and each having their own database with a DSN stored in the database.

    if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->company->active) {
        $uuid = $request->user()->company->db_uuid;
        $host = $request->user()->company->db_host;

        // here you can merge additional connection info in, such
        // as a master password from .env, for example
        $password = config('database.customer.master');

        // then set the default connection or assign a new one
        config(['database.connections.customer' => [
            'host' => $host,
            'password' => $password,
            'database' => $uuid,
            'username' => 'customer_master'
        ]]);

        return $next($request);
    }

    abort(403, 'Unauthorized');
}
```

Every query from there on in the request lifecycle will use that connection, without the need to set the connection each time.

Most of the models were specific to customer needs so we set the database connection in a base model and inherited where needed.

```
class BaseModel extends Model
{
    public function __construct($attributes = []) {
          parent::__construct($attributes);

          $this->connection = config('database.connections.customer');
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But not sure how to use dsn and would you guide me how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: DSN is just an acronym for datasource name. I probably should have used like organization id instead. The point being you might do a query to look up the database connection info. It could be as simple as the database name you want to connect to.

Comment: yeah. we can use organization id instead of dsn. To use database connection, it must be registered in confg/database.php I guess. Is it possible to use connection of organization id without registering it?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm getting at. You'd store the connection info in a "master" database, so to speak, and when a user authenticates, it reads the necessary connection info and then the middleware sets the connection on every subsequent request from there on out. If you do go this route, make sure you're not storing sensitive data as plain text. I built a crm system that stored a UUID on the organizations table and that was what we used to identify data base connections. Worked really well with 1000+ users/databases.

Comment: Amazing!!! But I'm worrying about the confliction from concurrent requests. Would you show me part of sample code? Thanks.

Comment: Ah unfortunately it's not available to me but I will update my answer here. It's not a whole lot different than what exists already.

Comment: I've updated my answer, there was pretty much it. With high concurrency/traffic you'll need to look towards a hardware solution eventually. Load balancers, master-slave databases, etc. all keep the system running smoothly.

Comment: config(...) method is valid for single request or all request. Can it be the later request  overwrite the before one?

Comment: in latest laravel version, it needs to reconnect the db because connection is already made before middleware. use DB::reconnect('db_name'); to reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration for your application is static unless changed via the files itself or .env.

If you wish to separate the database per user, you can store the connection name in the session instead.

An example:

`$users = DB::connection(session('databaseName'))->select(...);`

In your login action, you should set the session: `session(['databaseName' => 'secondDatabase']);`

Make sure that in your `database.php` that you have a connection called 'secondDatabase'.

Comment: How about in case of multiple databases not only secondDatabase?

Comment: You can provide as many database connections as you want in the config's array. If it's not a static number, then you'll want to create a custom system to handle this or figure out a different solution.

Comment: Well.. I don't think so. There must be solution for it I guess.